# Applying flow types to a constant function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, flowtype

I am trying to apply flow to some code.

The non-flow code is from the hooks implementation of https://v3.material-ui.com/demos/tables/#sorting-amp-selecting

```
const createSortHandler = property => event => {
  onRequestSort(event, property);
};
```

so this is an anonymous function (assigned to the const createSortHander) which takes a property and returns a function which takes and event and returns a method which happens to be onRequestSort?  Do I understand that correctly?

My attempts to apply flow have all failed so far, I feel I don't really understand the layers or abstraction here.

```
 const createSortHandler: (string) => void = (property: string) => {
        (event: Event) => {
            onRequestSort(event, property);
        };
    };
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The following code satisfies flow and works

```
 const createSortHandler: (string => (Event => void)) = (property: string) => (event: Event) => {
        onRequestSort((event: Event), (property: string));
    };
```